# Automount pendrive like Ubuntu Desktop in Ubuntu Server (15.10)

Tags: server, automount, usb-drive

I use the Ubuntu Desktop on my PC and want my Ubuntu Server to automount USB media just like it does on my Desktop: plugin, a folder with same name as label appears in /media/ with the device mounted.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

From the terminal issue the command `sudo apt-get install usbmount`

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24731/automounting-usb-sticks-on-debian